# Entity Framework temporary save

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

We are building a website where users can add/edit/remove students and their related info. Everything works great, but now we want to allow anonymous users to try our demo school.

Demo school is the same as regular school but we want users to be able to edit/delete information on the page without it being persisted in the database (This way this demo is always the same, despite of the user changes)

One way to do this is to run hourly SQL scripts that will clean-up records but this is not ideal because it will require running a scheduler, plus if user is trying out the demo sometimes data will be erased during their visit.

Is there a way to temporarily save data in a session or other storage and then wipe so demo is not affected?

Comment: Yes, by using a repository pattern that operates on in-memory objects instead on `DbSet<T>`, or by using a `DbContext` that doesn't actually write to the database. Please read [ask] and share your research.

Comment: -2 score and 4 close votes? Come on, this question isn't that bad. OP properly explained its issue, and already provided its current solution that isn't ideal...

Answer (score 0):

use a temporary database and as soon as you want to switch to the original one just change the web.config file , if you use Code first it will be easy else you need to generate sql+data from the original database to the temporary .

Answer (score 0):

You may use in memory objects as below

```
public class StudentManager
{
    public static List<Student> GetAllStudents()
    {
        return new List<Student>()
                   {
                       new Student { ID = 1, Name = "Mark", Gender = "Male", Department = "IT" },
                       new Student { ID = 2, Name = "Steve", Gender = "Male", Department = "HR" },
                       new Student { ID = 3, Name = "Ben", Gender = "Male", Department = "IT" },
                       new Student { ID = 4, Name = "Philip", Gender = "Male", Department = "IT" }
                   };
    }

    public static AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        // your logic
    }

    public static Edit(Student student)
    {
        // your logic
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```